# Direct Discriminative Pattern Mining for Effective Classification - implementation

Tags: data-mining, sequential-pattern-mining, pattern-recognition, discriminant-analysis

I'm looking for any actual working code implementation of the DDPMiner algorithm mentioned in the
[Direct Discriminative Pattern Mining for Effective Classification](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Exyan/papers/icde08_direct.pdf) article form 2008
I'm having real trouble trying to implement it myself.

Comment: You could try to contact the authors, sometimes it works. Hopefully my answer to your other question will help.

Comment: @Erwan Thanks I already tried to contact them without success, one of the authors replied and told me to contact the first author prof Hong Cheng, but she did not reply to my email.